# SpringBoot difference between @Configuration and @configurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot

From [spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor), `@ConfigurationProperties` will

> generate your own configuration metadata file from items annotated
>   with @ConfigurationProperties

I tried use `@Configuration` and `@ConfigurationProperties` separately on my configuration class.

```
@Component
//@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties 
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableAsync
public class AppConfig {
    ...
}
```

I didn't see any noticable difference.

What's the usage of `@ConfigurationProperties` or `@Configuration`?

Comment: Have you read the docs for `@Configuration`? It's pretty clear they do entirely different things.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`@Configuration` is used to create a class the creates new beans (by annotating its methods with `@Bean`):

```
@Configuration
public class CustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SomeClass someClass() {
        return new SomeClass();
    }
}
```

`@ConfigurationProperties` binds external configuration into the fields of the class which it annotates. It's common to use it with a `@Bean` method to create a new bean that encapsulates configuration which can be controlled externally.

Here's a real world example of how we've used it. Consider a simple POJO that holds some values related to connecting to ZooKeeper:

```
public class ZookeeperProperties
{
    private String connectUrl;

    private int sessionTimeoutMillis = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5);

    private int connectTimeoutMillis = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(15);

    private int retryMillis = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5);

    private int maxRetries = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    // getters and setters for the private fields
}
```

Now we can create a bean of type `ZookeeperProperties` and automatically populate it using external configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ZooKeeperConfiguration {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "zookeeper")
    @Bean
    public ZookeeperProperties zookeeperProperties() {

        // Now the object we create below will have its fields populated
        // with any external config that starts with "zookeeper" and
        // whose suffix matches a field name in the class.
        //
        // For example, we can set zookeeper.retryMillis=10000 in our
        // config files, environment, etc. to set the corresponding field
        return new ZookeeperProperties();
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is that it's less verbose than adding `@Value` to every field of `ZookeeperProperties`. Instead, you provide a single annotation on the `@Bean` method and Spring automatically binds any external configuration it finds with the matching prefix to the fields of that class.

It also lets different users of my class (i.e. anyone who creates a bean type of `ZookeeperProperties`) use their own prefix to configure the class.

Comment: Could you give me a usage case of `ConfigurationProperties`, I can directly get value from `aplication.properties` yaml file if I want to set some value externally.

Comment: Sure, I added a new example to the answer.

Comment: I believe there is also a shortcut for this setup; which is to annotate ZookeeperProperties with both `@Component` and `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="zookeeper")`.  This will make ZookeeperProperties autowire-able.  Of course, this is for only if no other `@Bean`s are in `ZookeeperConfiguration`.

Comment: another advantage of having defined this way is that you keep your configuration and the corresponding properties definition in one single place

Answer (score 6):

The use case of ConfigurationProperties is for externalizing configuration.

`@Configuration`

- Indicates that a class declares one or more `@Bean` methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime.

`@ConfigrationProperties`

-- Is added to a class definition or a `@Bean` method in a `@Configuration` class if you want to bind and validate some external Properties (e.g. from a .properties file).

See the screenshot to differentiate `@Value` from `@ConfigurationProperties`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.vs-value-annotation

[image: ConfigurationProperties use case]